# Angular 4 Freezes on Calling Function inside *ngFor

Tags: html, function, angular, typescript, web

I have a strange issue with my Angular app. Given this component:

[image: home.component.ts]

and this template:

[image: home.component.html]

the page will try to load forever until Chrome eventually prompts me to kill the tab.

It works fine if instead of `getDataForMonth(month)` I simply have a data object in `home.component.ts` named `monthData` and then feed `[data]` `"monthData"`

It also works fine in the following cases:

- I have a method in `home.component.ts` described as `hi() {}` and
  then feed `[data]` `hi()` in my html.
- I have a method in `home.component.ts` described as `hi() {return "hey";}` and
  then feed `[data]` `hi()` in my html.
- I have a method in `home.component.ts` described as `hi(month) {return month;}` and
  then feed `[data]` `hi(month)` in my html.

What is it about `getDataForMonth()` that could be breaking this? Is there some limitation here that I am unaware of? Is it possible it's some other issue not related to `getDataForMonth()`?

Comment: why do you have `month` parameter if the function does not use it?

Comment: @MurhafSousli Oops, I copied my code down wrong. Let me fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to precalculate function calls in *ngFor for performance reason. 
Add console.log to your getDataForMonth() method to see how often angular will call this function. 
Good way is to create array with function results for every month and iterate over it.

Comment: What is the difference between function and property? Both will be check in every change detection.

Comment: Do you have any idea why it would be breaking it though?

Comment: @ng2user Get property value is more cheaper then function call in javascript. Functions have a lot of overhead, creating context for example. This is not important for 10 function calls. But 10000 function calls will create performance issues. P.S. Sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

> "Don't use functions in bindings. your function will be called on
>   every change detection cycle. and angular runs x2 cycles in dev mode"

means never use {{ getDataForMonth() }} it will decrease your performance and its wrong way of coding.

You can try like this

Before *ngFor rendering create complete Object and pass to *ngFor

Comment: What is the difference between function and property? Both will be check in every change detection.